# Xcode - Unit Testing UIColor from asset catalog

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing

I wrote an extension for my Theme class that returns my mainColor based on my current theme. My unit tests cover theme changes but I still have problem with UIColor optional value. I can't cover the situation that UIColor could not able returns my specific color from my color catalog.

```
extension Theme {
var mainColor: UIColor {
    switch self {
        case .system:
          if let color = UIColor(named: "MainColor") {
             return color
          } else {
             return .clear
          }
        case .custom:
             return .yellow
      }
   }
}
```

I also used this line instead of unwrapping the optional but it didn't work too.

```
return UIColor(named: "MainColor") ?? .clear
```

How I unit test that the correct color is retrieved from the asset catalog?

Comment: [ask]: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.**

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to return a default color when your custom color cannot be found?

Comment: @BradleyMackey Yes, But I can't cover that default value in my tests. This is my main issue.

Comment: Looks like you need a `default` statement at the end of your `switch` statement.

Comment: Show declaration of Theme. You claim it is a class. Then how does it have cases you can switch on?

Comment: @MoeinBarzegaran I see. I would personally just force unwrap `UIColor(named: "MainColor")!` the color in my tests to assert the correct behaviour is occurring. This allows you to fix the problem right away (making sure the asset catalog is included in your test target).

Comment: “ I can't cover the situation that UIColor could not able returns my specific color from my color catalog.” You cannot cover it because it cannot arise. The color is in your asset catalog. Fetching it by name cannot fail. There is no point testing `UIColor(named)`; you know how it works.

Comment: @BradleyMackey Your solution worked but I think it isn't a good approach. Because If I change the color name in my assets it will crash and I can't find it.

Comment: And what on earth is an “implicit closure”?

Comment: @MoeinBarzegaran Please see my answer.

Comment: @gmdev `default` cases aren't needed in Swift if all the known cases are covered! :)

Comment: This is an example of useless test. You are trying to test the UIKit framework itself and whether resources are available (aka build settings). The code could be also simplified with `??` and the code would become simple enough that the correctness would be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally just force unwrap `UIColor(named: "MainColor")!` the color in my tests to assert the correct behaviour is occurring (that we are indeed able to access the desired color in the asset catalog). If we cannot access this color we will get a crash which, in a unit testing context, is actually desirable to isolate any problems.

I would also abstract the name of the color into an `enum` to ensure that the name is only defined in 1 place, then the possibility of naming inconsistencies between your app target and test target are removed.

```swift
enum Colors: String { 
    case main = "MainColor" 
}
```

Then use `UIColor(named: Colors.main.rawValue)` to access the color.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is a better way. I will use it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the name MainColor is hard coded, and either this color is in your asset catalog or it isn’t, and you cannot control for that in a test. You need to abstract this into a method to which you can pass the color name from the test.